# How to fix update code using short text as data type

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hello I just want to ask about my code. Why its showing error if I change the data type of ID_NO in short text? Btw database that I'm using is MS ACCESS

```
Dim i As Integer
i = dgMembers.CurrentRow.Index
currentid = dgMembers.Item(1, i).Value.ToString()
ds = New DataSet
adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("update [FASA_MembersAccount] set ID_No = '" & txtMemberIDNo.Text & "',[FirstName] = '" & txtMemberFirstName.Text & "',[LastName] ='" & txtMemberLastName.Text & "',[Mobile_No] = '" & txtMemberMobileNo.Text & "',[Gender] = '" & cbMemberGender.Text & "',[Birthday] = '" & dtpMember.Text & "',[Password] = '" & txtMemberPassword.Text & "',[Address] = '" & txtMemberAddress.Text & "' where ID_No = " & currentid, conn)
adapter.Fill(ds, "FASA_MembersAccount")
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What is your error... also I noticed that in the SET clause  IS_No has quotes indicating a character field but in the WHERE clause IS_No has no quotes indicating it is numeric... could this be your problem?

Comment: it shows failed to connect in database, Btw i declared the currentid as string

Comment: CurrentId may be a string but so it txtMemberIDNo.Text... why does your SQL have quotes in one spot and not the other?  One trick I use to locate possible SQL syntax errors is to put my SQL into a variable so when I debug I can extract it and run it in the database.

Comment: i can`t figure it out :-( can you give me a short example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to get your SQL code so you can run it in your database to check for syntax errors.  Does this help?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSQL as string
i = dgMembers.CurrentRow.Index
currentid = dgMembers.Item(1, i).Value.ToString()
ds = New DataSet

strSQL = "update [FASA_MembersAccount] set ID_No = '" &    txtMemberIDNo.Text & "',[FirstName] = '" & txtMemberFirstName.Text & "',[LastName] ='"   & txtMemberLastName.Text & "',[Mobile_No] = '" & txtMemberMobileNo.Text & "',[Gender] = '" & cbMemberGender.Text & "',[Birthday] = '" & dtpMember.Text & "',[Password] = '" & txtMemberPassword.Text & "',[Address] = '" & txtMemberAddress.Text & "' where ID_No = " & currentid

'--- Set your breakpoint here and use the immediate window to ?strSQL then copy/paste your command into ms-access
adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, conn)
adapter.Fill(ds, "FASA_MembersAccount")
```

Comment: Hello sorry for my late response i already got it. thank you so much

Comment: Do not concatenate strings with user input. Use parameters. You are risking Sql injection. It makes no sense to fill a dataset with an update statement.